# How to dynamically configure msal config and b2c policies in runtime using msal 2.0 in B2C for React

Tags: axios, azure-ad-b2c, msal

I want to dynamically setup msal config and b2c policies in runtime using msal 2.0 in B2C for react.

```
const msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(config);
```

So, I can swap the configuraton object for different environments Dev, UAT and Prod. For example, the hard-code configuration for b2c policies and msal config in Config.js is like:

```
export const b2cPolicies = {
    names: {
        signUpSignIn: 'B2C_1-Dev-Web-SignUpOrSignin',
        forgotPassword: 'B2C_1_PasswordResetv2'
    },
    authorities: {
        signUpSignIn: {
            authority: 'https://dev.b2clogin.com/tfp/dev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1-Dev-Web-SignUpOrSignin',
        },
        forgotPassword: {
            authority: 'https://dev.b2clogin.com/tfp/dev.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_PasswordResetV2',
        }
    },
    authorityDomain: 'dev.b2clogin.com',
};
```

```
export const msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: 'Dynamically setup for dev / test / production client ID',
        authority: b2cPolicies.authorities.signUpSignIn.authority,
        knownAuthorities: [b2cPolicies.authorityDomain],
        redirectUri: 'Dynamically setup for dev / test / production',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: 'Dynamically setup for dev / test / production'
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: false,
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', // Configures cache location. "sessionStorage" is more secure, but "localStorage" gives you SSO between tabs.
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // Set this to "true" if you are having issues on IE11 or Edge
    },
    system: {
        loggerOptions: {
            loggerCallback: (level: any, message: any, containsPii: any) => {
                if (containsPii) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (level) {
                    case LogLevel.Error:
                        console.error(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Info:
                        console.info(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Verbose:
                        console.debug(message);
                        return;
                    case LogLevel.Warning:
                        console.warn(message);
                        return;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
            },
        },
    }
};
```

I want to stored the configuration in a JSON file called parameter.json. Then Config.js can read from the parameter.json when start the react app. Axios/Http could be a good way but how I implement in the Config.js to read the configuration from parameter.json file? Thank you.

Comment: I have found the solution to use axios to get the settings from a local file and populate the msal configuration in run time.